# Visual Studio 2013 uses wrong Clone url

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I renamed my Git repository on team foundation server online and now I can't clone it anymore. I can connect to the team foundation project but cloning the repository fails, because there the old name is used for the repository URL. How can I force Visual Studio to use the correct repository URL?

Additional Information:
I already tried to initialize Visual Studio with no success.

> Source: http://www.corvalius.com/site/hacks/how-to-hard-reset-visual-studio-instance/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem like this a while ago. The way I did it was just use git in a shell to update the remote. I'm sure you can also do this in VS itself, but I found it easier to do it the 'old fashioned way'.

Just browse to your folder in git shell and use `git remote set-url origin https://repo.url`

After this, Visual Studio should use the new remote.

Comment: Sorry your answer is not working for me. Because I don't have a local clone of my "old" repository. I need to do a fresh clone. I can manually clone it with Git-GUI, but then the project is not recognized as a TFS-Project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Manually cloning (with Git-GUI) is working. First Visual Studio did not recognize that this is a TFS-project. But after restart of Visual Studio this was recognized correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions to close Visual Studio and open it again.

If so, you can try deleting the TFS cache from c:\Users[you]\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

Comment: Yes I restarted Visual Studio after doing the hard reset. (I stopped Visual Studio, did the hard reset and started Visual Studio again.)

Comment: Did you delete the cache? This is not included in the hard reset

Comment: No I didn't. After Gideon's method worked, I could not prove your way. But thanks to you too.

Comment: PS: Your TFS cache path is wrong. It can be found under %USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache